# Hide splash screen on android once phonegap site has loaded

Tags: javascript, eclipse, cordova, splash-screen

I have a website that uses media queries to look good on mobiles, I wrapped this up in phonegap so I can have it as an application too. I have set super.loadUrl to my site and this works, I also have a working splash screen that I want to keep up until the site has loaded. I came across [this blog post](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html) and followed the instructions. It works if I am super.loadUrl to index.html (the app homepage) but not if I loadUrl of my actual site.

Splash screen code (main java file)

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("My External Site Url", 20000);
```

Index.html code (this works if i loadUrl to it, but I want to loadUrl to my site)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

However, when I use the above code (and include cordova.js) in my external html file, it doesn't recognise onDeviceReady, so the splash screen doesn't hide itself, and I'm stuck waiting 20 seconds.

Am I missing something? Am I even allowed to use onDeviceReady from an external html file (e.g. one that is not build into the app) or should this work and I am just referencing cordova wrong?

Comment: Hey Andy, we have to figure out why you are not getting the deviceready event. If you don't get that event you won't be able to hide the splash screen. What do you see in "adb logcat" when you try to load this from a remote location?

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm not sure if this is what you need but I ran it through my AVD and this was put into the LogCat tab: http://pastebin.com/vRwBXENh

Comment: If it helps, when i do `alert('navigator: ' + navigator + '\nsplashscreen: ' + navigator.splashscreen);` (through a browser on my external html file, after including cordova) I get `navigator: [object Navigator], splashscreen: undefined` but I don't get an alert on my phone or emulator, not yet anyway

Comment: Yeah, you are never getting a deviceready event so PhoneGap is not successfully loaded. This is why navigator.splashscreen is undefined. You have an error in your JS which you can see in the log "http://192.168.1.4:8080/IntDemo/js/jquery.plugin.js: Line 13 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oSort' of undefined" and you should probably fix that first. Other than that if you can post your html to make sure you've set things up correctly.

Comment: In the login page: http://pastebin.com/cpLgU7fB, the javascript reference definitely works as when I view source and click it, cordova opens.
As for the javascript error, I am aware of that and it has been like that for a while, need to get round to fixing it but I don't think it affects it

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but in my IE console, loading the site in a browser (nothing to do with the app, except the fact cordova.js is still included) I got `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' ` on line 77 of cordova.js, so its definitely linking to Cordova.js

Comment: I've fixed the oSort JS error now, still the same problem with cordova though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out an old include of prototype.js was messing this up. Once I removed that it works awesomely.

For future people the errors I got were:

- App doesn't react to touch, input buttons and hyperlinks can't be used.
- If you press-hold on an input, hyperlink etc it got the orange focus box, but never took me to the link or activated the input button (cursor or keyboard)
- Prototype stopped me getting deviceready at any point, but no JS errors were thrown (except IE not liking addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<script> 
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
```

Although since you are using jQuery you may want to change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Frist add the splashscreen plugin as follow:

```
$ phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Second build the project,"splashscreen.js" will be merged into the "phonegap.js"

```
$ phonegap local build
```

Good Luck

Comment: Does answer the question asked in the OP?