# IBM Worklight - hiding splash screen

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen

I want to hide the screen splah of my app and i'm trying to do this with Cordova function `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` according to [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html)

```
function wlEnvInit(){
   wlCommonInit();
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
       alert("device is ready!");
       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
   }
}
```

I placed this code on `android/js/myAppName.js` and `iphone/js/myAppName.js` folders. It does not work. There is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you're trying to do is to hide the splash image at a point in time based on your own preference? This is currently not possible.

Worklight bypasses Cordova's splash image mechanism as well as does not provide an API to manipulate its duration programmatically (= choose when to hide it). This is an area that is destined to change in a future release.

If what you're trying to do is to simply not show a splash image at all, then:

- In iOS: this is not possible. The splash image is mandatory by Apple
- In Android: simply delete the `splash.9.png` image file from the `yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\native\res\drawable` folder

BTW, I do not see the use for the `deviceready` listener, because if you've reached `wlCommonInit`, then the device (Cordova...) has already been initialized. The app would not have functioned otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, a workaround for it would be by replacing the Splash screen image with a complete white background screen/image.

Comment: i think that on removing splash screen i could decrease loading time...can i do something working on native code(Java)?

Comment: Hmm, again from Apple its a requirement. But on Android device, I wouldn't think it will bring significant difference in performance. Its all about how you initialize your app, what variables or functions you call at the initialing/loading time

Comment: check this:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713212/hide-splash-screen-on-android-once-phonegap-site-has-loaded